# ASP.NET MVC return Index view after httpPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a two views in same controller. the issue is, i want to load second view after httppost is done.

**Index View**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

**HttpPost**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel model)
{

  return View("NEXTVIEW");

}
```

**Next View**

```
public ActionResult NEXTVIEW(EpmloyeeModal model)
{
  return View();
}
```

After HttpPost, I have added return to nextview. whereas it always return back to Index view. I tried to find such scenario on different websites, but could not find anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel model)
{
  return RedirectToAction("NEXTVIEW");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For post action, use this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel model)
{
   return RedirectToAction("NEXTVIEW");
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was late for answer ;(

Answer (score 5):

Your next view action is expecting a model, you need to pass it the EpmloyeeModal model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel model)
{
  return RedirectToAction("NEXTVIEW",new EpmloyeeModal());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Post Use, the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel model)
{
   return RedirectToAction("NEXTVIEW"); // Redirect to your NextView
}
```