# ASP.NET Core MVC does not open View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app and such controller definition:

```cs
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IWeatherService _weatherService;

    public MainController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWeatherService weatherService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _weatherService = weatherService;
    }

    public IActionResult SelectCity()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowChart([FromForm] SettelmentModel settelment)
    {
        var lat = double.Parse(settelment.Lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var lon = double.Parse(settelment.Long, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var data = await _weatherService.GetHistoricalForecast(lat, lon);
      
        return View("ShowChart", data);
    }
}
```

The app processes the `ShowChart` method and finds the `ShowChart` view, but does not open it in the browser. And just stays on the same View from `ShowChart` method was requested.
I expected it would route to `/Main/Chart` and would open the Chart view.
What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have a `<form>` in the `SelectCity` view, or do you POST to `ShowChart` with ajax?

Comment: In which folder do you have the _ShowChart.cshtml_ file?

Comment: @GSerg, yes, i have a form in SelectCity View, but i do POST  with ajax.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879239/asp-net-mvc-return-index-view-after-httppost) should have what you're looking for. Mirror the top answer.

Comment: @Steve, in folder Main, which named like controller

Comment: If you post with ajax, then naturally it's your responsibility to receive the response in the javascript code and insert it into the appropriate part of the page. If you want to replace the entire page with the response, then it's much easier to not post with ajax and just let the browser do it.

Comment: @GSerg, it seems, i have understand what do you meen. I will change my code and will give feedbeck. Thank you  for your help!